# Network connection was lost during `application:openURL:options`

Tags: ios, react-native, networking, nsurlsession, deep-linking

We are using deep links to complete verification for an app we're working on. Said deep links cause the app delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
```

To be called. This app is using React Native, using the in-build `Linking` API. Some of the time making a network request when we get the `Linking` callback works, but sometimes we get a networking error:

```
Task <D47D1F90-E2D1-4AB7-8706-8737B68CC5E8>.<180> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x283352ac0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x281ed9130 [0x1e9babcb0]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb34d2847e0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D47D1F90-E2D1-4AB7-8706-8737B68CC5E8>.<180>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <D47D1F90-E2D1-4AB7-8706-8737B68CC5E8>.<180>"
```

I've had a pretty extensive google and it seems to be suggested that this can be caused when a network request is made in the background, however Apple quite clearly state in the docs for this method:

> If a URL arrives while your app is suspended or running in the background, the system moves your app to the foreground prior to calling this method.

Is there something we shouldn't be doing here? Has anyone else seen similar issues?

**Update**

It seems this works fine first time the link is opened after app-launch, but subsequent calls fail. Nothing seems to be called in a different order, so it's very confusing why we'd see this sort of pattern!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with `URLSession` being retained but the underlying TCP socket being reclaimed by the OS, and there are a couple of solutions which Apple support suggest which can be seen [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4279#issuecomment-447108981).

In my scenario, I didn't want to go playing around with the internal `URLSession` usage within React Native, so we simply now retry the request once and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I've got same problem and I notice this happens only with a short-form of link. According to the document, a short link is related with network.

> To create a short Dynamic Link, build a DynamicLinkComponents the same way, and then call shorten().
>
> Building a short link requires a network call, so instead of directly returning the link, shorten() accepts a completion handler, which is called when the request completes. For example:

I am guessing there is a network problem with apple API or firebase API.

So here is my solution. I create a new category and function called handleUniversalLinkDelayNetorkCall. I moved all source code from handleUniversalLink and just call resolveShortLink after some delay.

Sorry for my english and see full source code.

```
@implementation FIRDynamicLinks (FIRDynamicLinks_HandleUniversalLink_BugFixed)

- (BOOL)handleUniversalLinkDelayNetorkCall:(NSURL *)universalLinkURL completion:(FIRDynamicLinkUniversalLinkHandler)completion {

    if ([self matchesShortLinkFormat:universalLinkURL]) {
        
        // delay call
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            
            __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
            [self resolveShortLink:universalLinkURL
                        completion:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                if (strongSelf) {
                    FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [strongSelf dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        completion(dynamicLink, error);
                    });
                } else {
                    completion(nil, nil);
                }
            }];
        });

        return YES;
    } else {
        FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [self dynamicLinkFromUniversalLinkURL:universalLinkURL];
        if (dynamicLink) {
            completion(dynamicLink, nil);
            return YES;
        }
    }
    
    return NO;
}
```

This works for me. Cheers.